# Why should we run Linpack with LDA greater than N?

Tags: performance

The LINPACK benchmark is a test for rating the performance of a computer on a simple linear algebra problem.  What do you usually put for the inputs?

Specifically, leading dimension of array:  The documentation says:

"The leading dimension must be no less than the number of equations.
Experience has shown that the best performance for a given problem size
is obtained when the leading dimension is set to the nearest odd 
multiple of 8 (16 for Intel(R) Itanium(R) 2 processors) equal to or
larger than the number of equations (divisible by 8 but not by 16, or
divisible by 16 but not 32 for Intel(R) Itanium(R) 2 processors)."

Why is that the case for best performance?